# Diferença entre declaração de scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

Existe alguma diferença nessa declaração de scope mencionado na documentação do angular:

```
myApp.controller('DoubleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.double = function(value) { return value * 2; };
}]);
```

para esse scope?

```
myApp.controller('DoubleController', function($scope) {
  $scope.double = function(value) { return value * 2; };
});
```

aparentemente, ambos funcionam igualmente da mesma forma

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sim, existem diferenças.

A segunda utiliza o apelido padrão do servico `$scope`, que é homônimo.

A primeira cria uma injeção do serviço `$scope`, e utiliza o apelido '$scope' para referenciar este serviço.

Esta implementação permite maior flexibilidade - imagine um controller genérico, que você pode invocar passando diferentes serviços como referência:

```
myApp.controller('DoubleController', ['servicoTipo1', function(servico) {
  servico.funcao();
}]);

myApp.controller('DoubleController', ['servicoTipo2', function(servico) {
  servico.funcao();
}]);
```

A implementação do controller é a mesma, e a chamada à função `funcao()` também - porém os serviços são diferentes.

Este modelo é muito usado quando você deseja implementar *controllers* reutilizáveis:

```
myApp.controller('controleBase', function(servico) {
  servico.funcao();
});

myApp.controller(
    'controleDerivado1', [
        '$scope',
        '$controller',
        'servico1',
        function ($scope, $controller, servico) {

            $controller('controleBase', { $scope: $scope }); 
            //Invoca uma nova cópia de controleBase, 
            //utilizando servico como referencia de servico1; 
        }\);
```

Comment: Dúvida: Isso é útil também pro caso de minificar o arquivo? Se o segundo exemplo postado pelo AP fosse minificado, provavelmente ele teria o parâmetro `$scope` trocado por um `a` (ou algum nome parecido) que o AngularJS iria ignorar. Ou o que falei não tem nada a ver?

Comment: @renan Me parece uma boa idéia. Eu não vejo porque um bom *postprocessing parser* não realizaria essa minificação, mas confesso que ignoro a existência de algum que faça isso.